# Button for sqrt sign

Tags: button

How to create a button, which has exactly the same functionality as pressing ctlr+2 in an inputField?
So it is basicly appending an sqrt sign to a string.

Comment: Um, did you try searching on your own ? Like, `CreatePalette`, etc ?

Answer (score 2):

```
CreatePalette[{"Square root",PasteButton[Sqrt@\[SelectionPlaceholder]]}]
```

Comment: Can't just ignore simplicity and readability; +1

Comment: In a .nb notebook, it opens a new notebook for the palette everytime i run it, and if I try to close this palette, it asks me if i want to save it or not. ...strange